# java.lang.IllegalStateException: No JTA UserTransaction available. war deployment in jboss not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jboss

I am working on a spring boot application. when i build it using maven and run its jar it works properly. however when i change its packaging property to war in pom.xml and deploy the generated war file in Jboss the following error occurs

here is my application.properties

```
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
spring.servlet.multipart.file-size-threshold=2KB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=215MB
file.upload-dir=/Users/anand.yadav/uploads
app.upload.dir=/Users/anand.yadav/uploads
jts.port=3333;
jts.ip=192.168.55.36
omnidocs.cabinet=iformscab
omnidocs.parentfolderindex=2266
server.port=8080
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://xxxxxxxxxxx
spring.datasource.username=xxxxxxx
spring.datasource.password=xxxxxxx
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

here are the server logs

```
2020-05-01 12:21:17,449 INFO  [io.undertow.servlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 346) Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-05-01 12:21:19,461 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 346) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/omnipedia2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/omnipedia2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT": java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5dbd4e28]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/transaction/jta/JndiJtaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No JTA UserTransaction available - specify either 'userTransaction' or 'userTransactionName' or 'transactionManager' or 'transactionManagerName'
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:85)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5dbd4e28]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/transaction/jta/JndiJtaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No JTA UserTransaction available - specify either 'userTransaction' or 'userTransactionName' or 'transactionManager' or 'transactionManagerName'
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:231)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5dbd4e28]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/transaction/jta/JndiJtaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No JTA UserTransaction available - specify either 'userTransaction' or 'userTransactionName' or 'transactionManager' or 'transactionManagerName'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:285)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:392)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
```

here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.newgen</groupId>
    <artifactId>omnipedia2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>omnipedia2</name>
    <description>omnipedia demo</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>         
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ISPack</groupId>
            <artifactId>ISPack</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jdts</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdts</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>NIPLJ</groupId>
            <artifactId>NIPLJ</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nsms</groupId>
            <artifactId>nsms</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>omnishared</groupId>
            <artifactId>omnishared</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>wfdesktop</groupId>
            <artifactId>wfdesktop</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j-1.2.14</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-1.2.14</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>itextpdf-5.5.8</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf-5.5.8</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: can you show your dependencies, i.e. `pom.xml`?

Comment: added pom.xml. all dependencies

Comment: do you want to use JTA?

Comment: No, i do not want JTA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to disable it as described in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.9.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-jta.html#boot-features-jta):

> If you are within a JTA environment and still want to use local transactions, you can set the spring.jta.enabled property to false to disable the JTA auto-configuration.

So please add `spring.jta.enabled=false` to your `application.properties`.